# python: psql: insert into table on conditions

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I have a psql table "inlezen" with columns "tagnaam" and "melding".
Now I want to insert a string into column "meldingen" if "tagnaam" equals a variable "foutetag".

I have tried some queries, messed with the syntax but couldn't get it to work.
This is my code:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO inlezen (melding) WHERE tagnaam == foutetag VALUES (%s)", ("Fout bij schrijven naar OPC Server",)) 
conn.commit()
```

But it gives errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OPCSchrijvenLezen.py", line 71, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO inlezen (melding) WHERE tagnaam == foutetag VALUES (%s)", ("Fout bij schrijven naar OPC Server",)) 
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO inlezen (melding) WHERE tagnaam == foutetag VALU...
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this piece of code?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit after Mathias Ettinger's answer:**

I've changed the code and the error changed a little bit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OPCSchrijvenLezen.py", line 72, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO inlezen (melding) WHERE tagnaam = %s VALUES (%s)", (foutetag, "Fout bij schrijven naar OPC Server",))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO inlezen (melding) WHERE tagnaam = 'Bakkerij.Devi...
                                      ^
```

Now it "sees" the content of the variable at least. However, there are single quotation marks around the variable. I'm not sure if they should be there.
If I print the variable "foutetag" it just shows:

```
Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT8
```

, like it is in the psql table.

This is how I generate the variable:

```
foutetag = [item[0] for item in taglistwaardennieuw]
foutetag = (", ".join(foutetag))
```

Could there be anything wrong the way I generate the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `foutetag` is a variable, then you need to treat it like so:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO inlezen (melding) WHERE tagnaam=%s VALUES (%s)", (foutetag, "Fout bij schrijven naar OPC Server",))
```

Also note the single `=` in the `WHERE` clause.

However the `INSERT` statement does not accept a `WHERE` clause, as it will produce a new row from scratch. If you want to update your value, use:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE inlezen SET melding=%s WHERE tagnaam=%s", ("Fout bij schrijven naar OPC Server", foutetag))
```

Comment: I've replied in my OP.

Comment: Updated. Your SQL statement was ill formed from the beginning